# How to add conditional where conditional in query laravel framework?

Tags: laravel

> Actually the scenario is my queries are running on the basis of if
>   condition. In first scenario

```
if ($a != "") {
    $getData = DB::table('students')->where([
        ['code', '=', '1'],
        ['class', '!=', 'General'],
        ['gender', '=', 'm']
    ]);
}

> //second scenario

if ($b != '') {
    $queryData = $getData->where(ST_Distancesphere(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($longt, $latt), 4326)), '<', $b)->get();
} else {
    $queryData = $getData->get();
}
return $queryData;
```

> in first scenario query is working fine but when $b is not equal to
>   blank then where condition is not working

Comment: Can you please tell what error is occured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to use `ST_Distancesphere` method, you need to use the raw sql.
So if you use `whereRaw()` like this, and set binding for **preventing SQL Injection**:

```php
$queryData=$getData->whereRaw("ST_Distancesphere(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:lng,:lat), 4326)) < :b", ["lng" => $longt, "lat" => $latt, "b" => $b])
                   ->get();
```

However, you have different bindings' way before this query,

```php
DB::table('students')->where([['code', '=', '1'],['class', '!=', 'General'],['gender','=', 'm']])
```

Laravel will get `Invalid parameter number` error.

So I think you need to change the previous bindings, make them all use same bindings' way:

```php
if($a != "") {
    $getData = DB::table('students')
               ->whereRaw("code = :code AND class != :class AND gender = :gender", ["code" => 1, "class" => "General", "gender" => "m"]);
}

if($b != '') {
    $queryData=$getData->whereRaw(" ST_Distancesphere(geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longt, :latt), 4326)) < :b", ["longt" => $longt, "latt" => $latt, "b" => $b])->get();
} else {
    $queryData=$getData->get();
}
return $queryData;
```

Comment: the second query did not send any response or any error.

Comment: My ajax response send me 200 but query didn't send any response or any error when condition is $b !=''

Comment: When I am trying to print the query to add ->toSQL() in that case its not printing anything

Comment: `->toSql()` need to before `->get()`; and do u try the raw sql in mysql, and did it return records?

Comment: actually query is not printing so how i can check in mysql

Comment: Is there any way to check if its go in this condition or not means in if($b!='')

Comment: you can just `dd('xxx')` in the condition, if it prints nothing, means not go into condition.

Comment: @sumitkundan so it doesn't go into the condition, you need to check your `$b`'s value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206333/discussion-between-sumit-kundan-and-tsaikoga).

Answer (score 1):

follow official documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses